# Ruby: undefined method `<'

Tags: ruby

I just started learning Ruby and I ran into a problem:

```
  def gas
    @speed += @velocity if @speed < @max_speed
  end
```

*in 'gas': undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)*

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `@speed` in `if @speed` is not defined or has `nil` value.
Try this:

```
def gas
  @speed ||= 0
  @speed += @velocity if @speed < @max_speed
end
```

Or, initialize `@speed` with some value elsewhere (Probably in `initialization`.

Comment: You should strike "is not defined or" in your first sentence. Ruby first converts `@speed += <right side>` to `@speed = @speed + <right side>`. If `@speed` is undefined, Ruby converts the expression to `@speed = nil + <right side>`, so `@speed < @max_speed` is subsequently evaluated `nil < @max_speed`.  (I'm not quibbling!) Also, "try this" is irrelevant and possibly misleading.